# How to forcefully reload all sections using IGListKit?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iglistkit

Is there any approach to **update all sections forcefully**?  
As IGListKit is working with a diff algorithm, that's why sections don't update if the **identifier** isn't changed.
But I locked some logos for **premium**. when users purchase my app, IGListKit didn't update the section instantly and didn't remove the lock icon from the Logo. Because I diff my model with **Logo's name**. As Logo's name isn't changed, that's why sections are not automatically updated. So I need to update all sections forcefully when users purchase my app.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After so much research, I ended up with a solution. 
If you just need to reload all sections at any purpose without diffing, you can write following code

```
[self.adapter reloadDataWithCompletion:nil];
```